# Can't compile in Visual Basic 2010, get an error

Tags: vb.net, compilation, release, visual-studio-express

I made a program in Visual Basic 2010 Express on a computer running Windows XP.

It compiled and ran correctly, but then I "released" it

Releasing failed and now, every time when I try to compile, I get this error:

```
Error   1   Unable to write manifest 'obj\x86\Debug\[PROJECTNAME].exe.manifest'. Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
    [PROJECTNAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `error CS0002` is undocumented. Obviously it looks like it has something to do with loading strings, but that's awfully hard to diagnose the actual error with. Something looks really broken.  I would recommend you get a clean install of the .NET framework and go from there. II would also ensure that you have read and write permissions on your `%windir%\Temp` folder.
 You can find some further information you may find useful  [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eeaa52fb-3faa-4424-98d6-e44bb2dc9f9d/error-messages-when-publishing-with-visual-studio-2010?forum=vsdebug)  regarding the same error.